# how pass json string objective class to swift class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift3

1. My SDK method objective c class
2. Using -Bridging-Header called objective method from swift class
3. returning string from objective c class but that jSON added \n
4. how to solve this Please help me

   ```
   "{\n  \"DeviceName\" : \"iPhone\",\n  \"HardwareID\" : \"**********\",\n  \"DeviceModel\" : \"iPhone\",\n  \"WiFiNetworksData\" : {\n    \"BBSID\" : \"******\",\n    \"SSID\" : \"*****\"\n  },\n  \"CustomDecimal\" : 3.14159,\n  \"DeviceSystemVersion\"}
   ```

Comment: Why don't you replace "\n" by empty string?

Comment: You want to convert this string to dictionary?

Comment: @Nikhil : i tried replace string  doesn't work

Comment: @nirav: i need string to make rest api call

Comment: @NagendarReddy It is already a string make api call then

Comment: yeah but string contains "\n  \ " i need to pass json string  api

Comment: that is not valid json string

Comment: actual my SDK output string {
  "DeviceName" : "iPhone",
  "HardwareID" : “***”,
  "DeviceModel" : "iPhone",
  "WiFiNetworksData" : {
    "BBSID" : “****”,
    "SSID" : ""
  },
  "CustomDecimal" : 3.14159,
  "DeviceSystemVersion" : "10.0.1"
} when i passing to swift class it is changing like above sting

Comment: Is [this](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/convert-json-string-to-nsdictionary-in-swift/) not working for you?

Comment: while i am print string it is correct and when i am passing it is changing why i did understand

Answer (score -1):

i got solution for this 
When i debugging code in debug area console window showed like \n but it is  contains normal string only, working fine now.

Comment: This section is for answers only.

Comment: You should disable the *pretty printed* option when creating the JSON.